# How to avoid starting sentences with "And" or "But"?

Tags: conjunctions, sentence-patterns, sentence-starts

A lot of times my sentences start with "And" and "But" and they tend to run long. I read a lot of news articles and blogs and have not seen many sentences starting with conjunctions, but I don't seem to get the trick of how to avoid it.

English is my second language.

Comment: Suggest relocating this question to Writers.SE.

Comment: This question doesn't really belong here because there's no right answer to it.  You are correct that starting a sentence with a preposition (such as "and" or "but" is considered bad style, but your question is too general for people to be able to provide a useful answer.

Comment: @MetaEd: I concur. As is often the case when the fundamental answer is "proofread and revise," this does seem to be more of a writing question than an English question.

Comment: alright, how to move it to writers SE?

Comment: It's a stylistic element, just as fragments. And, honestly, I like to use both. Not necessarily in the same sentence, though. But here and there.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to start sentences with conjunctions, you are free to do so.

A simple way to do it would be simply to stop using *and, but,* and *or* to connect clauses or phrases. Connecting words, between two words, or before the last of a list of words, **OK**:

- *I saw Bill **and** Bob at the picnic.*
- *I saw Bill, Bob, Ben, Mary, **and** Sarah at the picnic.*

But **not**

- *I saw Bill and Jen saw Bob but they were both with somebody else, or maybe they were alone, and ....*
- *He arrived on time, but then he went back to the car and got a gun, or talked to somebody, and ...*

There's nothing wrong with these sentences, mind you. They're perfectly normal, the way people talk all the time. **But** if that's the way you talk, you probably don't want to write that way; as you say, it goes on and on. And it's good practice to try something else.

So take your time and try to become aware of conjoined clauses. A good exercise is to write each clause as its own sentence. Then figure out how they should be arranged to get your ideas across. Without conjunctions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're conjoining two independent clauses, you can replace the conjunction with an adverb or adverbial phrase.

- And → Additionally, | Also, | Furthermore, | Likewise, | Moreover, | etc.
- But → However, | Nevertheless, | On the other hand, | etc.

> I read a lot of news articles and blogs and have not seen many sentences starting with conjunctions.  **However,** I don't seem to get the trick of how to avoid it.

Comment: That advice is like "use long words in place of short words" and can add to the problem instead of ameliorating it.

Comment: I don't believe I've ever seen an edit where adding "however" or "nevertheless" to the beginning of a sentence made it better.